# SystemVerilog: How come the enum next() method cannot be used in a constant function?

Tags: enums, constants, enumeration, system-verilog, compile-time-constant

I have a package containing a number of packed-struct typedefs and I am trying to write a CONSTANT function to tell me the maximum bit width of these structs. Each struct has an explicit message_type which is enumerated. I believe the below function I have written should be interpreted by the compiler as constant, but I am getting the error "(vlog-2118) The function 'get_max_message_length' is not a valid constant function" (this is in ModelSim).

Can anyone tell me why this function is not constant? After debugging I have determined that it is the enum method 'next()' that is causing it to be interpreted wrong. Any possible alternate solutions? Thank you in advance!

```
typedef enum logic [7:0]
{
   MESSAGE_TYPE_0=0,
   MESSAGE_TYPE_1=1,
   MESSAGE_TYPE_2=2
} _MSGTYPE;

function integer get_message_length (_MSGTYPE message_type);
   case (message_type)
      MESSAGE_TYPE_0: return ($bits(message_0));
      MESSAGE_TYPE_1: return ($bits(message_1));
      MESSAGE_TYPE_2: return ($bits(message_2));
      default: return 0;
   endcase
endfunction

function integer get_max_message_length ();
   automatic _MSGTYPE largest = largest.first();
   automatic _MSGTYPE next = next.first();
   next = next.next();
   while (next != next.first()) begin
      largest = get_message_length(largest) > get_message_length(next) ? largest : next;
      next = next.next();
   end
   return get_message_length(largest);
endfunction
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A constant function has certain restrictions - it must be a [pure function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) (i.e. have no side effects and return the same value if called with the same arguments).

This restriction propagates, so your constant function can only call other functions that are also pure functions.  The problem you have is that `next.next()` is not a pure function - it does not return the same value every time you call it.

Sadly the SystemVerilog LRM doesn't appear to define any `pure` mechanism for accessing enumerated values - for example this *would* work if it were possible:  `for (int i=0; i<enum.num(); i++) size=get_message_length(enum.item(i));`

Off the top of my head I can't think of a neat way to do this.  You could create a localparam which was an array of enum values and iterate over that but you'd have to write out the enum values again.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I will have to use the for loop method and make sure that the enums are consecutive.